# Определение вызывающего родителя

Tags: php, функции

Функция_А вызывает функцию_Б.

Подскажите пожалуйста, можно ли как-то находясь внутри функции_Б определить какая функция её вызвала?

И ещё интересует другая ситуация, а если вместо функции_А например просто скрипт, можно ли как-то определить это, чтобы например показало "main".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Обычно, для этого получают стек вызова при помощи функции `debug_backtrace()`. Первый элемент будет содержать информацию о текущей функции, второй - об непосредственно родителе. Например:

```
<?php
function b($str)
{
    echo "From b: $str<br >";
    $funcs = debug_backtrace();
    echo "Parent: ". $funcs[1]['function'];
}

function a($str)
{
    b($str);
}

a('Hello world!');
```

Результат

```
From b: Hello world!
Parent: a
```